# Is it ok to use both nested and shallow resources in rails? How to write the controller/views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources, controller, nested

I have resources for which it makes perfect sense to address them both as nested withing other resources and separately. I.e. i expect to use all urls like these:

```
/account/4/transfers   # all transfers which belong to an account
/user/2/transfers      # all transfers input by specific user
/project/1/transfers   # all transfers relevant to a project
/transfers             # all transfers
```

my concern is how do I write TransfersController actions (for example index) as it would double the logic found in parent models - is there a better way than doing something like

```
TransfersController
...
def index
  if !params[account_id].nil?
    @account = Account.find(params[account_id])
    @transfers = @account.transfers
  elsif !params[user_id].nil?
    @user = User.find(params[user_id])
    if @user.accesible_by?(current_user)
      @transfers = @user.transfers
    end
  elsif !params[projects_id].nil?
    .....
```

and the same holds for views - although they all will list transfers they will have  very different headers, navigation etc for user, account, project, ...

I hope that you see the pattern from this example. I think there should be some non-ugly solution to this. Basically I would love to separate the logic which selects the transfers to be displayed and other things like context specific parts of view.

Answer (score 3):

I've got an open question on this. In my question I outline the 2 methods I came up with. I'm using the second currently, and it's working pretty well.

[Routing nested resources in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025050/routing-nested-resources-in-rails-3)

The route I'm using is a bit different because I'm using usernames in place of the IDs, and I want them first. You would stick with something like:

```
namespace :projects, :path => 'projects/:project_id' do
  resources :transfers #=> controllers/projects/transfers_controller.rb
end

# app/controllers/projects/transfers_controller.rb
module Projects
  class TransfersController < ApplicationController
    # actions that expect a :project_id param
  end
end

# app/controllers/transfers_controller.rb
class TransfersController < ApplicationController
  # your typical actions without any project handling
end
```

The reason I use the namespace instead of a call to `resources` is to have Rails let me use a separate controller with separate views to handle the same model, rather than pushing all the nasty conditional logic into my controller actions.

Comment: What would be the placement of views using this model? Does it play nicely with the fact that Project has_many :transfers etc.. ?

Comment: In the namespaced routing above, the views for `project_transfers` would be at `views/projects/transfers/*` and views for regular `transfers` would be at `views/transfers/*`. If this doesn't fit what you're trying to do, the other option of a shallow-nested route with handling in the controller might be better suited. I'd love to hear another way though (hence the question I asked).

Comment: Ok, I have thought about your solution and I actually think it might be a good one, but I still have a feeling, that we are working somehow "against" rails. If there are concepts like nested routing, build in support for :has_many, it feels odd that there is no counterpart for these in terms of writing controller in case one model is nested on several places.

Comment: I have read your question and it is interesting what you ask for. Why you want /:username/photos and not /users/:user_id/photos or /users/:username/photos?

Comment: @gom Namespaces are built into Rails. I don't see how using them is against Rails. If this isn't what you want, you can go with using a conditional to handle different parameters in your controller action or define your routes individually to map to different actions based on the parameters received.

Comment: @coreyward Ok, maybe the "against Rails" are far too strong words. I do not thinkthat namespaces are any bad. I want to say that I would expect something better (probably you too) suited for this case. If we have nested resources, than all information is already there and IMHO by using naespaces you are not beeing very DRY - you basically duplicate the :has_many or nesting inforation by using namespaces. This is what feels odd.

Comment: I don't namespace the models. Rails will fallback on the regular model if it doesn't find a namespaced one.