# How do I write/organize my Rails controllers and routes to allow access to deeply nested resources at each level?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, controller

First of all, coreyward asks and answers this question well on a shallow level, but I don't understand well enough.

If I expand on coreyward's example, I can imagine a photo site that's intent on emphasizing curation. Photos are meant to be displayed in albums, and one photo can appear in many albums. In addition, photos have many tags.

So User has_many :albums, :photos, and :tags, Album has_many :photos and :tags (by way of photos), Photo has_many :tags, etc.

So the main way of looking at a photo will be through /users/123/albums/456/photos/789. Photos will have a unique ID, so I could do simply access /photos/789, but I think the URL is a valuable wayfinding tool in the user experience and would prefer it to be clear that this is a photo in a particular album belonging to a particular user. Like coreyward, I would also like to use vanity URLs (url slugs) in a few places.

Even if I routed the #show and #index actions in the simplest ways possible (e.g. /photos/789 and /albums/456/photos), #new and #create would be a little more problematic. If I opened /users/123/albums/456/photos/new, the user could upload a photo, which would get the user_id 123 AND the app would be smart enough to create a join table (album_photos or what have you) entry without asking the user to make this association in a separate step.

There would still be scenarios where someone, depending on permissions, would want to see /users/123/photos or just /photos, /albums, /tags.

I'd like to avoid conditional logic n the controllers like coreyward suggested, but having app/controllers/photos_controller.rb, app/controllers/users/photos_controller.rb, and app/controllers/users/albums/photos_controller.rb seems nasty.

How should I deal with something like this (in Rails 3)?

Thanks!

Comment: Forgot to provide a link to the original question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025050/routing-nested-resources-in-rails-3

Comment: Another example: If I were making a site like ESPN.com, to look at Penn State football's page, I might access `/sports/ncaaf/leagues/big-10/teams/psu`.  Still, someone might want to see all leagues across sports (`/leagues`, all teams across sports (`/teams`), all teams across a given sport (`/sports/ncaaf/teams`), irrespective of league, etc. Ignore the fact that there are multiple `psu`s (diff sports), multiple `big-10`s (likewise), etc.  This seems a thorny problem to me.

Answer (score 1):

You got it all wrong man. You don't have to have a `users/photos_controller.rb` under any circumstance. You can just have a `users_controller.rb` and `photos_controller.rb` and then get as fancy as you want with the routing:

```
resources :users do
  resources :albums do
    resources :photos
  end
end

# and also provide unnested access to photos and albums
resources :photos, :albums
```

look [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) for some examples BUT pay attention where it says: "Resources should never be nested more than 1 level deep". Thing are going to get really messy really fast on you especially when you have to start writing junk like:

```
link to 'photo', users_albums_photos_path(:user_id => 3, :album_id => 7)
```

YUCK! Really, nested routing is something that should be used sparingly and avoided at all costs. What you are describing does not sound like a good candidate for nested routing at all (the fact that I can load up a picture without its album is a red flag). There are other ways to protect access to resources than through the routes

Comment: Thx. I hear what you're saying about avoiding nesting routes deeply, but what are the "other ways to protect access"?  I can manage user privileges so some users can't see /photos/789, etc, but I would still like all of those URLs to be available to some user in some circumstance.  I'm leaning toward giving up on this ideal and just using the shallowest possible routes. I can still display the user to whom a photo belongs (`@photo.user`) tho not which album it's being viewed in, e.g.  But I still think there's a strong case to be made for the usability of verbose URLs for wayfinding.