# Rails routing issue during POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, routes

I'm new to rails, stuck at weird junction.The issue is related to routes.
Below is my code

**routes**$

```
resources :users do
 resources :requests 
end
```

***user.rb***

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessor :password
 attr_accessible :email, :firstname, :lastname, :state, :city, :password
 has_many :requests ,:foreign_key => :user_id,:autosave => :true
```

***request.rb***

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :email, :status, :user_id,:token
belongs_to :user
```

***Request form html***

```
 <%= form_for (user_requests_path) do |f| %>
<div class="field">

<%= f.label "Email" %><br />
<div class="fieldgroup">

<%= f.text_field :email  , :class=>"textfield"%>

</div>
<div id="spacer">

</div>
<div class="fieldgroup">
<%= f.submit "Invite", :class=>"custombutton" %>
  </div>
   <% end %>
</div>
```

When I click on Invite button under request form
I'm encountering following error rather than calling request#create.

Routing Error

`No route matches [POST] "/users/9/requests/new"`

***Request controller***

```
def create
@user = User.find(params[:user_id])
@request = @user.requests.create(params[:request])
redirect_to user_path(@user)
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

To do so, you should set up the [Nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) in your `routes.rb`.

See also: [Routing nested resources in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025050/routing-nested-resources-in-rails-3)

Comment: resources :users do
      resources :requests 
   end I did this

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the user object, so rails which user instance you refer to:

```
<%= form_for (user_requests_path(@user)) do |f| %>
```

Also in:

```
has_many :requests ,:foreign_key => :user_id,:autosave => :true
```

You do not need to pass `:foreign_key => :user_id`, that is the default foreign key, ie "model_id"

Answer (score 0):

For nested resources, you need to pass both parameters to some helpers, so, e.g.,

```
user_request_path(@user, @request)
```

And so on.  The Rails Resources Guide is a big help.