# Rails 4 - Routing & Namespaces?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ok, so - What did I do wrong?  I feel like I'm missing something very simple...

REQUESTS belongs to USER

USER has many REQUESTS

I'm logged in as current_user (id=3) and want to list my requests:

`<%= link_to("My Requests", user_requests_path(current_user)) %>`

That link goes to `/users/3/requests`, but it shows ALL requests, not just those belonging to me.... ???

```
routes.rb
    resources :users do
      resources :requests
    end

rake routes:
 user_requests GET      /users/:user_id/requests(.:format)     requests#index
```

Comment: Not answerable based on what you've posted. Is the right action being routed to? Is that action filtering requests correctly? And can you possibly strive to be a *little* more professional in your posts?

Comment: My apologies for offending you with my attempt at levity.

Comment: Do you look for levity in Wikipedia? If it doesn't go there, then it doesn't go here. Stack Overflow is meant to be a work of reference, not a forum.

Comment: Understood; hence my apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't related to your routes, then, it's a scoping problem on your ActiveRecord query. You probably have something like the following in RequestsController:

```
def index
  @requests = Request.all
end
```

But what you need to have is something more like the following:

```
def index
  @requests = current_user.requests
end
```

If your Request resource can be accessed independently of users (i.e. there's a use-case for `Request.all` or `/requests`) you should actually do a separate namespaced controller (e.g. `Users::RequestsController`) to handle user-specific requests. Your routes will then need to specify the namespace for the user-specific requests as well.

Comment: My index is:  `@requests = Request.paginate(:page => params[:page])`    Hm, but what if I want to use the same index for listing all requests?  so, one link goes to my requests and another link lists all requests... I thought the current_user param would filter the view.  ??

Comment: @KatieM I've updated my answer with a little more information on that case. You might also want to check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025050/routing-nested-resources-in-rails-3

Comment: Gotcha, I'll check it out and accept your answer when it allows me to.  Thanks!